# WSO2: Where to get a working Eclipse plugin from to start WSO2 from within Eclipse?

Tags: web-services, eclipse-plugin, wso2, remote-debugging

I have an Eclipse Luna installation and want to start the already installed WSO2 5.2.1 from within Eclipse. How can I do this and where can I get a plugin which is able to be installed successfully? I tried to install it via Eclipse Marketplace but always get an error

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://dist.wso2.org/p2/developer-studio/releases/3.6.0/plugins/org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.libraries-3.6.0.jar.
>   Connection reset

I also tried to download the WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.0 (wso2-developer-studio_3.7.0.zip) but it also doesn't work.

In the end I want to start the WSO2 Application Server from within Eclipse and to debug the implemented web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first I ran Eclipse under jdk 1.6.30. Now with jdk 1.7.45 I see a lot of WSO2 features...
Correction:
I had to install WSO2 Developer Studio 3.6.0 via Eclipse Marketplace first and have to update to version 3.7.0 afterwards because http://dist.wso2.org/p2/developer-studio/releases/3.7.0/plugins/org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.libraries-3.7.0.jar is not readable.